# Как сделать в Hibernate автоинкремент не для столбца id

Tags: hibernate

Как сделать в  Hibernate автоинкремент не для столбца id(postgerSQL)?

Пример класса Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
@Table(name = "travel_agency_reise_coop")
public class TravelAgency {
@Id
private String name;
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Date createdAt;
@Column(name = "modified_at")
private Date modifiedAt;
private String owner;
private String address;
private String zipCode;
private String city;
private String phone;
private String fax;
private String email;
private String webSite;
private String openingHours;
private String requestUrl;
@Column(name = "homepage_id")
private int homePageId;
@Column(name = "request_zipcode")
private int requestZipCode;
```

Comment: Если поле проаннотировать как `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` - не работает? Обычно приводят какой-то код (например, класса, который сохраняется в БД), пишут что пробовали сделать.

Comment: Добавил код)strategy не работает в данном случае

Comment: значит в два запроса.первый раз извлекаете и узнаете макс.число.Потом сохраняете новую запись с добавлением 1 к макс.числу.

Comment: Либо триггером в самой БД :-)